# Pop up but no window shown (SDL2 on m1 Ventura)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sdl-2, apple-m1

I am trying to setup sdl2 on my mac and all headers get detected in my test code. When I compile and run the code it should open a fully red window but the only thing that I get is a pop up on my task bar that I can't click on. I had similar problems with pygame and I assume it's due to the fact I try it on an M1 chip.

Cmake File:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(SDLTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(SDLTest main.cpp)
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.26.4/include)
set(SDL2_LIBRARIES /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.26.4/lib/libSDL2.dylib)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Code:

```
int main( int argc, char * args [] )
{
    SDL_Window * window;
    SDL_Renderer * renderer;
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    // Check for successful initialization
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) != 0 )
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    // Create window and renderer using the Metal backend
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "metal");
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer( 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &window, &renderer );

    // Set the render draw color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255 );

    // Clear the screen with the render draw color
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

    // Update the screen with any changes made to the renderer
    SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );

    // Wait for 3 seconds before exiting
    SDL_Delay( 3000 );

    // Clean up SDL
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use an event loop?

Comment: Yea, event loop it was.